# Restarting Nginx affect mysql?

Tags: mysql, nginx, restart

Does restarting my Nginx service in Ubuntu affect the mysql service? an example would be, if I stop the nginx service, would the traffic to website stop and the mysql database/service still work?

I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MySQL service its self will continue to run, so if you are using it via CLI, or a remote connection that will not be interrupted.

However if you were for example using a PHP script which was being run by nginx and had an open connection to MySQL, that connection could be terminated and the user may get some kind of error.

Comment: Thanks, even though it was a bit too late for me to read this, I still appreciate it and gave you the answered check button, thank you again

Answer (score 0):

safest way is to reload it and it won't touch the mysql for those interested that is the answer, so instead of writing sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart you simply change restart to reload